# A question relating to certain algebraic manipulation of a formal power series written in the form of infinite product

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions, formal-power-series

Suppose there is formal power series in infinite product form as follows: $$\prod_{d\geq 1} \left(1+\frac{u^d}{q^d-1}\right)^{a_d}$$, where $a_d$ are positive integers. Consider the expression $$\prod_{d\geq 1} \left(1+\frac{u^d}{q^d-1}\right)^{a_d}-1$$

Now, this expression has no 1 in it. So, when expressed as formal power series, the expression has the form $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_nx^n$. Now, my question is can we write the above expression in an infinite product form as above by taking something out as common term. So, for example, observe that $b_1=\frac{a_1}{q-1}$. So, possibly can we write

$$\prod_{d\geq 1} \left(1+\frac{u^d}{q^d-1}\right)^{a_d}-1=\frac{a_1}{q-1}u\times (\text{an infinite product expression})$$ 
or, maybe in the form (Exponential generating function)$\times$ (an infinite product expression).

We note that the coefficients $b_n$ has the following form:

$$b_n=\sum_{\lambda \vdash n} \prod_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\binom{a_i}{m_i(\lambda)}}{(q^i-1)^{m_i(\lambda)}}$$

where, $\lambda\vdash n$ means $\lambda$ is a partiton of  $n$ (hence the outer sum runs over all partitons of $n$), and $m_{i}(\lambda)$ denotes the number of times $i$ occur in the partition $\lambda$.

I know that my question probably seems a little confusing as it doesn't perfectly mention what exactly is it that I want to know, but anyway this is the best I could frame it. Thanks in advance for any kind of help.

Comment: Have you tried writing out what the $b_i$ are?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury I am editing the question by writing the form of $b_i$ that I think is correct. Please rectify me if it's not the right answer.

Comment: Maybe something of this form: for example: $\left[(1+\frac{u}{q-1})^{a_1}-1\right] \prod_{d\geq 1} (1+\frac{u^{d+1}}{q^{d+1}-1})^{a_{d+1}}$. But observe that in this case the coefficient are not $b_i$, they are of the form $b_i-\frac{a^d}{q^d-1}$. I mean to say that I want my expression to be written in some kind of product form as above, but ofcourse the above one doesn't work.

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Did you get anything? I mean does my comment atleast make the question a little precise?